# Laravel - Como configurar projeto para abrir no XAMPP?

Tags: laravel, xampp

Tenho um projeto em `Laravel`, porém por um motivo em especifico tive que desinstalar o XAMPP e instalar novamente.
Agora não lembro o que devo mudar nos arquivos de configuração do XAMPP para fazer o projeto rodar.
Já alterei o caminho do projeto no arquivo httpd do xampp, porém não roda.
Ao tentar rodar o comando php artisan migrate dá erro a seguir:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'sgpmehos_bd' (SQL: select * from `permissions`)
>   [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'sgpmehos_bd'
>   C:\Users\Lucas\Dropbox\TCC\Vagrant\www\html\TCC\patrimonio>php artisan migrate
>   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sgpmehos_bd.permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `permissions`)
>   [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sgpmehos_bd.permissions' doesn't exist

Alguém tem alguma orientação?

Comment: O erro do `artisan` é banco não encontrado, banco inexistente (`sgpmehos_bd`), esse banco existe ?

Comment: Sim, Virgilio. Esse banco existe. Criei o database, mas ao rodar esse comando dá erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você configurou o arquivo .env na pasta database do Laravel?

Coloque as informações do seu banco nesse arquivo, informando o nome do banco,
usuário e senha.

Se já tiver feito isso.

Vá no terminal que estiver usando no diretório da sua aplicação digite:

php artisan key:generate

depois.

php artisan cache:clear

depois

php artisan config:cache

e por fim start no servidor.

php artisan serve.

Comment: Allan, vou verificar isso assim que chegar em casa e te dou um retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique seu arquivo de migration se estiver assim:

```
Schema::table('tabela1', function ($table)  {
    // ... 
});´
```

Para criação de novas tabela deve-se usar **Schema::create**

```
Schema::create('tabela1', function ($table)  {
    // ...
});
```